# Using the GP Web Services, is it possible to do Intercompany Distributions for Payables Transactions?

Tags: dynamics-gp

```
invoice.IsIntercompanyTransaction = true;
invoice.HasIntercompanyDistributions = true;

var dist = new PayablesDistribution();
dist.CompanyKey = new CompanyKey { Id = 2 }; // different company
```

Consider the code above. All three of the properties set are said to be read-only in the Dynamics GP 2010 Web Service Reference. So is it even possible to do Intercompany transactions using only GP Web Services?

Below is a link to the same question, asked by someone else, on the Dynamics Community board.
http://community.dynamics.com/gp/f/32/t/106478.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to create intercompany payables transactions using GP Web Services or eConnect. I have seen some creative solutions that involved direct SQL updates following the import to set the intercompany flags though this method is not supported by Microsoft.